# Spring Flash Attributes not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following controller code redirecting to a page:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/site_form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String welcomeForm(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute Site s,
        BindingResult br, RedirectAttributes ra) {
    if (br.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("errors", br.getAllErrors());
        return "hello";
    }
    model.addAttribute("message", "Entry Log");
    model.addAttribute("site", s);
    ra.addAttribute("flash", "Site saved successfully");
    return "redirect:/app/admin/site_form";
```

I'm trying to access ${flash} in the controller, but cannot.

Also, I though this was supposed to go in the session, but my URL after the redirect URL hit as a get attribute.

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be `ra.addFlashAttribute("flash", "...")`.